# Google Apps script : setValue unable to get results on google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api, setvalue

I made a script for YouTube search results. I placed my keywords in column A2 & A3. Script is working fine as I am getting the results of 1st & 2nd Keyword (you can see in log pic) but I am only able to retrieve the results of first keyword on my sheet.

```
function youTubeSearchResults() {

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

 for (let i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++){

 let keywords = sheet.getRange(2+i,1).getValue();

// Do Search On YouTube
 let searchResults = YouTube.Search.list("id, snippet", {q:keywords, maxResults: 10, type: "video", order: "viewCount", videoDuration: "short", order: "date"});

// Filter Search Results By Kind From searchResults Variable
 let fSearchResults = searchResults.items.filter(function(sr) {return sr.id.kind === "youtube#video"});

// Map Search Results In An Array From fSearchResults Variable
 let modifyResults = fSearchResults.map(function(sr) { return [sr.id.videoId, sr.snippet.title, sr.snippet.publishedAt, sr.snippet.channelTitle, sr.snippet.channelId, sr.snippet.thumbnails.high.url] } );

// Parse modifyResults Variable Values in Sheet
  sheet.getRange(2+i, 2, modifyResults.length, modifyResults[0].length).setValues(modifyResults);
     
 }
}
```

[Apps Script log of both keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbxMK.png)

[output data on google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I72bU.png)

can you please help me how to get the results of second keyword on my sheet too, or if I add more keywords then all the results simultaneously.

I have no coding background so please make it simple for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `i` of `sheet.getRange(2+i, 2, modifyResults.length, modifyResults[0].length).setValues(modifyResults);` is the row number. But, the length of `modifyResults` is different from `i`. I thought that this is the reason of your issue of `but I am only able to retrieve the results of first keyword on my sheet`.
- When `getValue` and `setValues` are used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function youTubeSearchResults() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const modifyResults = values.flatMap(([keywords]) => {
    const searchResults = YouTube.Search.list("id, snippet", { q: keywords, maxResults: 10, type: "video", order: "viewCount", videoDuration: "short", order: "date" });
    const fSearchResults = searchResults.items.filter(function (sr) { return sr.id.kind === "youtube#video" });
    return fSearchResults.map(function (sr) { return [sr.id.videoId, sr.snippet.title, sr.snippet.publishedAt, sr.snippet.channelTitle, sr.snippet.channelId, sr.snippet.thumbnails.high.url] });
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, modifyResults.length, modifyResults[0].length).setValues(modifyResults);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: How can I add View count and Subscriber Count ?

Comment: @tamey Thank you for replying. From `Thank you it works like a charm.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: New Question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838721/how-can-i-add-view-count-and-subscriber-count) @tanaike

Comment: can you please help me with this error of your modified Script [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888344/google-sheets-not-iterable) @tanaike